# How can i rotate gridview on page?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I want to rotate gridview in Web Form to print it clear because it doesn't fit in portrait orientation of the page. Gridview is going after `page-break-before:always;`
But when I rotate it, it cuts 50% of the grid for some strange reasons.
How can I rotate grid and make it fit 100% on the page ?
I want to have something like this :
[image]
But i have this situation
[image]
My CSS to rotate :

```
.gridCss {
    width: 100%; 
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);  
    font-size:8px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height:100%;
}
```

My code:

```
<div class="gridCss"  style="page-break-before:always;"   >
    <br />
    <br />          
    <center CssClass="rotateText" > <asp:Label ID="MainLbl" runat="server"  />  &nbsp;и</center> <br />
    <center CssClass="rotateText" ><asp:Label ID="Lab1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></center> <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DSI" Width="100%"   >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="one" HeaderText=""  SortExpression="1" HtmlEncode="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="fio" HeaderText="two" SortExpression="2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="3" HeaderText="" SortExpression="3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="4" HeaderText="К4" SortExpression="4" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="5" SortExpression="Date" />
          ...
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSI" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectSta %>" SelectCommand="Command" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Sess" SessionField="Sess" Type="String" />

            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="st" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="nr" Type="String" />

        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <tr>
        <td class="abz"/>
        <td align="right"> 
        <pre>        
            &#9;_______
            <asp:Label ID="Label_gv_2"        runat="server" Text="_____"></asp:Label>
            _______    __________________ &#9;Дата:___
            <asp:Label ID="Label_dt_2" runat="server" Text="_____"></asp:Label>
            ________ &#9;&#9;(ФИО)&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;(подпись)<br />
        </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Add generated html instead of `asp.net` tags. Also, how it looks now, doesn't seem to valid html; and you are missing non prefixed css for rotate `transform: rotate(90deg); `

Answer (score 0):

I used DevExpress Data Grid that supports [export and printing](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Exporting/Exporting.aspx) with extended options, including document [page orientation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraPrinting.LinkBase.Landscape.property). If you do not need the grid, you can use their [reporting tool](https://demos.devexpress.com/XtraReportsDemos/ReportTypes/TableReport.aspx) to print tabled data.